# `getExternalStorageDirectory()` issue - Android

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I'm writing an android application that takes some pictures and would like to save them all in a unique directory associated to my application.

This directory should be accessible from the standard Gallery, in such a way that the user can later (when application is not necessarily running) check the pictures that were taken.

My problem is that every different phone vendor, with a different android version, has different paths for gallery.As an example:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES +"/myFolder"
```

will work on `Samsung Galaxy Nexus` running `android 4.1.1`, and on `Asus Transformer Pad` running `android 4.0.3`, but not on `HTC Desire` running `android 2.3.5`.

This will cause my application to crash when trying to save a new directory within the specified path, as stated below:

```
boolean success = false;
myFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/myFolder" );

if( myFolder.exists() ){
//do nothing        
}else{

    success = dvaFolder.mkdir();

if( success ){
    // Do something on success
    /*
     * folder has been created
     */

} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
    /*
     * folder creation failed
     */
    throw new RuntimeException("File Error in writing new folder");
}
}
```

> How can I write a directory that will be accessible in gallery for all
>   different vendors and android versions?

**NOTE:**

Logcat isn't much useful, cause it just returns the run time Exception.

Comment: I've just had the same problem. That path should be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`.

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin - thks for pointing out. Actually I managed to solve the problem on my one quite a long time ago. But you should post your answer so I can accept it if it works.

Comment: Ok, I posted my working code which works without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with the bluetooth folder, I created a two methods to search for the bluetooth folder on the phone, by traversing the whole file structure on the phone. The code I wrote is beneath, it is a bit dirty, but it works quite well in my case

```
public List<File> folderSearchBT(File src, String folder) {

    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] filesAndDirs = src.listFiles();


    if (filesAndDirs != null && filesAndDirs.length > 0) {
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);

        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            result.add(file); // always add, even if directory
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                List<File> deeperList = folderSearchBT(file, folder);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Use the method above in this method:

```
public String searchForGallery() {

    String splitchar = "/";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    List<File> btFolder = null;
    String folder = "gallery"; //your foldername to search for..
    btFolder = folderSearchBT(root, folder);

    if(btFolder.size() < 1)
        Log.i("btFolder: ", "Empty");

    for (int i = 0; i < btFolder.size(); i++) {

        String g = btFolder.get(i).toString();

        String[] subf = g.split(splitchar);

        String s = subf[subf.length - 1].toUpperCase();

        boolean equals = s.equalsIgnoreCase(folder);

        if (equals)
            return g;
    }
    return null; //not found
}
```

By saying that the code is dirty, I mean that I could wrote it more compact and another issue by doing it this way: if there are two folders with the name bluetooth, I'm stuck..

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you succeeded or not

Comment: Hey Tobias, I just got home and had a chance to check your code. Unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for, cause I need to create that folder at a given and known path, and not look for it. Thanks anyway, other handy ideas? ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code for taking picture and saving to external storage and another method for saving to 'files' directory on device. In my case I needed only one image (something.png) which will be always refreshed after user takes new picture.

Action when user clicks on button for camera:

```
ImageView productImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
static int RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
String selectedImagePath;
Bitmap bitmap;
String imageName = "something.png";

public void cameraImageButton_onClick(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    dir = new File(path, imageName);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(dir));
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Action which is performed on activity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        selectedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                + File.separator + imageName;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        options.inSampleSize = Calculator.calculateInSampleSize(options,
                254, 254);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        productImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        saveImage(bitmap, imageName);

    }

}
```

Bonus method for saving image to device in *files* directory if someone needs:

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString()
            + File.separator;
    File dir = new File(path);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    path = path + name;
    dir = new File(path);

    try {
        dir.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        fos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thks, I'll try it and let you know as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you have included the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission in your application Manifest, it could give such errors.
Also, have you checked that the path does not simply look invalid by printing it?

Comment: I have the permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. And when I print the path it seems fine: `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/myFolder`. Nevertheless application crashes...